# Pdf generation with table of content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, pdf-generation

I'm creating a web portal for financial institute and we were asked to create a report with table of contents and page numbers and headings. For example, this report looks like ordinary ebook that contains images, table of contents, page numbers, headings, etc.

We are using ASP.net MVC 3, Entity framework and MSSQL server for our infrastructure.

What are the options that I have for considering this pdf generation ? 
Are there any open source solutions ?

I'm familiar with docbook approach XSLT and XSFO, however these bit hard to implement and complex.

What we are searching is a easy apporach ?

Comment: You probably want to look at [How do I programmatically create a PDF in my .NET application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-pdf-in-my-net-application).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ItextSharp DLL to generate pdf with Table as you want.

you can download from below link.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/